# Is there a procedure that could potentially restore my hard disk to reliable operation?

Tags: hard-drive, smart, bad-sectors

Some time ago my main hard disk started going really slow.  S.M.A.R.T. tests were failing or giving errors so I bought another one.

Now, my dying hard disk is not totally dead; sometimes it works and sometimes it does not respond. I don't know much about hard drives, I heard something about fixing/excluding bad blocks, for example.

I'm not asking anyone to speculate on whether the drive can be restored to normal operation.  Rather, I'm asking whether there is something I can do to attempt it.

Here is the output from smartctl showing the S.M.A.R.T. status:

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-24-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Momentus 7200.5
Device Model:     ST9750420AS
Serial Number:    5WS39PH3
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 044d9c362
Firmware Version: 0002SDM1
User Capacity:    750.156.374.016 bytes [750 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Fri Jun 17 16:19:31 2016 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 121) The previous self-test completed having
                    the read element of the test failed.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 145) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   3) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x103f) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   086   085   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       58105720
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   097   097   085    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   095   095   020    Old_age   Always       -       5396
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   094   094   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       1104
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   078   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       78302452
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       4792
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   098   098   020    Old_age   Always       -       2698
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       1976
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       8590065666
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   054   050   045    Old_age   Always       -       46 (Min/Max 26/47)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       11
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       200
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   074   074   000    Old_age   Always       -       53623
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   046   050   000    Old_age   Always       -       46 (0 13 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x001a   113   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       58105720
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       16
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       16
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       4665 (96 200 0)
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       62268680
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       2787857734

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 39 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 39 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4787 hours (199 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was doing SMART Offline or Self-test.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 90 79 aa 0c  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0caa7990 = 212498832

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 80 00 63 aa 4c 00      22:54:27.080  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 80 62 aa 4c 00      22:54:26.636  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 00 46 aa 4c 00      22:54:11.157  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 80 38 aa 4c 00      22:53:58.978  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 00 38 aa 4c 00      22:53:58.608  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 38 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4787 hours (199 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was doing SMART Offline or Self-test.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 20 fc a9 0c  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0ca9fc20 = 212466720

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 80 80 d1 a9 4c 00      22:52:58.524  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 00 d1 a9 4c 00      22:52:58.087  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 80 c4 a9 4c 00      22:52:55.032  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 00 b3 a9 4c 00      22:52:44.893  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 80 ae a9 4c 00      22:52:39.635  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 37 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4787 hours (199 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was doing SMART Offline or Self-test.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 08 4b ee 08  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x08ee4b08 = 149834504

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 80 c0 32 ee 48 00      22:47:57.728  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 40 32 ee 48 00      22:47:57.309  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 40 de ed 48 00      22:47:35.757  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 40 c0 ed 48 00      22:47:22.729  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 c0 bc ed 48 00      22:47:18.609  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 36 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4787 hours (199 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was doing SMART Offline or Self-test.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 f0 05 04 0c  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0c0405f0 = 201590256

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 80 f8 f7 03 4c 00      22:26:02.664  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 78 ea 03 4c 00      22:25:52.850  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 f8 e9 03 4c 00      22:25:52.513  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 f8 e0 03 4c 00      22:25:44.348  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 f8 c8 03 4c 00      22:25:31.550  READ FPDMA QUEUED

Error 35 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 4787 hours (199 days + 11 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was doing SMART Offline or Self-test.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 00 10 a8 a1 0c  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0ca1a810 = 211920912

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  60 00 80 80 a3 a1 4c 00      22:02:41.297  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 00 a3 a1 4c 00      22:02:40.680  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 00 94 a1 4c 00      22:02:33.976  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 80 78 a1 4c 00      22:02:14.948  READ FPDMA QUEUED
  60 00 80 00 78 a1 4c 00      22:02:14.710  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      4792         203277224
# 2  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%      4792         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      4792         -
# 4  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      4789         185089992
# 5  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%      4773         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      4765         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: If you have backed up the drive and the data is no longer important, try deleting the partition table, and creating a new one and reformatting the drive, if that works then try the SMART tests again. I have had more than one drive work for some time after this, others continued to fail. Either way, I would not rely on this drive for anything but temporary or short term use.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I was thinking about something like that

Comment: When you reformat, do a "low level" format that retests all the sectors.  A "quick format" won't really do much that would be useful.

Comment: I decided to trash the disk, I can't even read the partitions anymore :)